# Can I remove this outlet and fill it?

Tags: receptacle, exterior, removal

I have this exterior outlet connected to a conduit that i want to remove. I’ve tested the outlet with an outlet tester and it says it’s cold. I don’t really want to try to remove the entire conduit as it goes underneath a slab/ patio. I was gonna just saw it off and then fill the conduit with silicone caulking. Is there anything else I should take into consideration?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there wires? Where do they go to?

Comment: If the wires serving this outlet are in good shape, if they are present in a breaker panel and *capable* of delivering power, you should decommission this in a way that isn't permanent.  You may want power here for some reason in future, and running underground conduit is hard work.  Even if the wires are in bad shape, you could hopefully use them to pull new wires.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the other end of the conduit and determine what breaker entergizes the outlet. It could still be live with a faulty outlet that doesn't register voltage. The conduit could start in another outlet or light fixture outside,in the house or in the panel. Check the panel door for breaker numbers for outside outlets.

Once you determine where it's fed from, disconnect the wires and recheck the outlet box you want to remove. If unenergized, you can go ahead with your plan.

Comment: The outlet is about 25 feet from the house.  The slab in the pic is between the house and the conduit so I assume the conduit runs under the slab towards the house.  Short of digging a trench perpendicular to the assumed conduit, is there any other way of locating where the conduit might run?  Also, breaker panel is ~5 years old and doesn't list anything about exterior outlets.  There is one other ext outlet attached to side of house (works) in line with this old one, one might think they are connected?

Comment: Open up the other outlet and watch while someone tugs on the wire at the outlet you want to decommission.

Comment: Or blow air (compressor, backwards shopvac) into the decom conduit and look/listen.

Comment: I'd suggest using a metal detector to trace the conduit.  But to answer your base question, if you're sure you want to permanently remove this outlet, the line feeding to this outlet needs to be found and the line disconnected and made such that it can never be connected again, since the far end you've removed is no longer viable.